# What are the equivalents in Sass and LESS of these features?

Tags: sass, less

I'm a LESS user, but I'm considering trying out Sass. Each of them have one big thing that I find attractive, and I'm wondering if both frameworks have equivalents (third-party programs included)

**Reason to use Sass (AFAIU):**

- Sass can be set up to auto-compile into CSS files, saving the need to manually do it

  - With LESS, the closest is using SimpLESS, but that is still a manual step

**Reason to use LESS:**

- LESS Elements - A set of commonly used mixins (e.g. rounded corners, box-shadow, etc.)

  - Something similar can be made in Sass, if not available, but I'd like to know if it's already been done

Comment: Theres a meta framework for SASS called Compass http://compass-style.org/ , it contains a lot more than LESS Elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that might clear your doubts:

- With LessCSS you include a .js file on your page that doesn't require any other manual step.. That's much simpler than any other method, and I guess you didn't know that.
- Less.app for Mac does the work great, and to me, it's better to just launch the app which works than to type "sass --watch etc" in Terminal. Less.app compiles your .less files on every file save, also those which are referenced in the main stylesheet (SimpLESS app doesn't seem to have an option to compile on file save).
- I use Twitter's Bootstrap "CSS library/framework" for prototypes/projects, it's fantastic and the code is written in .less format. For me this is a reason I won't switch back to Sass (used it for a while). Check out http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Compass looks good, from what I can see it offers exactly what Bootstrap offers, maybe in a more structured way - but I don't see a demo of what it can offer by default, so I don't see myself using it anytime soon. Also, the $7 app.. sorry, got it for free with Less.app.

Comment: I know that LESS can just be included, but I've found that there is a little bit of a wait during page load (pre-cache), where all the elements are unstyled, then the styles are added (short, but noticeable). Additionally, the .less stylesheet isn't minified, and there time is spent on actually running the LESS script. Compass not having a demo is what turned me away from it a bit. But I do hear good things about it. I haven't heard of Bootstrap, so I'll definitely check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, some people don't want to rely on .js when working with less.. but then why not use Less.app (or SimpLESS) and minify there?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now (SimpLESS). And don't get me wrong, it's awesome. I just heard that with Sass, you could set it up to automatically compile the .less into a .css file upon saving it. With SimpLESS, you have to alt-tab and press compile. It's not serious, but if it can be automated, that'd just make things better.

Comment: That's why I "stressed" on using Less.app by mentioning it in the first place - it compiles on every file save (even those which are imported into the main one, chained imports trigger a compile, that's awesome), and it's a true time saver :) I haven't tried SimpLESS until few minutes ago and I can see that it can't deliver. Only Less.app!

Comment: AFAIK Mac only :(. However I did just stumble on WinLess(http://winless.org/), which looks like it solves the auto-compile issue